# Non-independence of bootstrap samples

Tags: probability, bootstrap, independence

### Background

Suppose we have a dataset that consists of $n$ iid random variables represented as $X_j$, where $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$. We know $\forall i,\, 
\operatorname{E}\left(X_i\right) = \mu$, and that 
$\operatorname{Var}\left(X_i\right) = \sigma^2$.

Suppose further that we generate $B$ bootstrap samples from this data, with the $i$th element of the $b$th bootstrap sample denoted by $X_i^{∗b}$.

> We want to show that $\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_i^{∗b},\,X_j^{∗b}\right) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n}$.

We already know $\operatorname{E}\left(X_i^{∗b}\right) = \mu$ and $\operatorname{Var}\left(X_i^{∗b}\right) = \sigma^2$ (refer to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/370341/expectation-and-variance-of-bootstrap-samples) for these computations).

### Current attempt

My instinct is to consider any two constituents of a given bootstrap sample as independent, meaning their covariance should be 0.

But I understand why this instinct may be taking me in the wrong direction: I assumed an implicit condition when I stated that two "sample constituents" should be independent:

> Namely, I assumed that the data the bootstramp sample was being created from has already been "realized".

In mathematical terms, what I was referring to is:

$$\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_i^{∗b},\,X_j^{∗b}\bigg|X_1,\ldots,\,X_n\right) = 0$$

And while this is true, it is not what we want to compute -- $\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_i^{∗b},\,X_j^{∗b}\right)$ is an unconditional covariance.

For some $i,\,j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ s.t. $i \ne j$:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
\operatorname{Cov}\left(X_i^{∗b},\,X_j^{∗b}\right) &= \operatorname{E}\left[\left(X_i^{∗b} - \operatorname{E}\left(X_i^{∗b}\right)\right)\left(X_j^{∗b} - \operatorname{E}\left(X_j^{∗b}\right)\right)\right]\\
& = \operatorname{E}\left[\left(X_i^{∗b} - \mu\right)\left(X_j^{∗b} - \mu\right)\right]\\
& = \operatorname{E}\left(X_i^{∗b} X_j^{∗b} - \mu X_i^{∗b} - \mu X_j^{∗b} + \mu^2\right)\\
& = \operatorname{E}\left(X_i^{∗b} X_j^{∗b}\right) - \mu \operatorname{E}\left(X_i^{∗b} - X_j^{∗b}\right) + \mu^2\\
& = \operatorname{E}\left(X_i^{∗b} X_j^{∗b}\right) + \mu^2\\
& = \sum_{i = 1}^n \sum_{j = 1}^n X_i X_j \operatorname{Pr}\left(X_i^{∗b} = X_i,\,X_j^{∗b} = X_j\right) + \mu^2\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

And this is where I get stuck.

### Question

I am not sure how to show $\operatorname{E}\left(X_i^{∗b} X_j^{∗b}\right) = \frac{\sigma^2}{n} - \mu^2$.

Comment: You seem to use "$\operatorname{Cov}$" in several different ways.  If you're going to condition on the sample, please notice that because it's a *sample* it has no property that is directly relatable to $\sigma^2$: the covariance of the sample could literally be any number mathematically consistent with the range of the underlying distribution of the $X_i.$  How, then, have you any hope of proving what you want if you use the definition you provide after "mathematical terms"?

Comment: @whuber Thank you for your comment. "[B]ecause it's a *sample* it has no property that is directly relatable to $\sigma^2$": this is new to me, and I see your point. In this context I also see why I got stuck in the last line of my computation of the covariance. With this, I'll work on the computation again and post my conclusions if I can reach what I desire.